# Getting reference document element by name using javascript

Tags: javascript

A basic question I assume for someone who does JS on a daily basis.
I'm helping a friend that does not use the recent sweets (JQuery, prototype and co.).

How should I get a reference to a document element by name ?

I would like to allow a selection user does in a `<SELECT />` element modify the value of an `<INPUT />` element.

Both elements don't have ID fields defined, only names.

This should be portably obviously (Mozilla, IE, Opera).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/htmldom/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) function which will return an array of all elements having a given name:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName('some_name');
```

Comment: Thank you, was doing getElementByName. Note the missing (s).

Comment: Personally I prefer $("some_name") :-)

Comment: @cletus: *That's* convenient! When did it get included in vanilla JavaScript? ;-)

Comment: @cletus: that's not event included in the recent sweets!

Comment: Since when do we start letting such minor issues as that prevent us from bigging up jQuery huh?

Comment: Note: IE is still buggy on this returning elements with a matching ID attribute. (it won't affect the poster, but one should be aware of this bug)

Answer (score 0):

If `<input>` and `<select>` are members of the same `<form>` element, you can reference the fields directly, they are members of the form object:

```
<form>
  <select name="bar" onchange="this.form.foo.value = this.value;">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="foo">
</form>
```

You can wrap it in a function, of course.